# How to display summary of user permissions from a data table into a row

Tags: user-centered-design, data-tables, cards, dynamic-ui, permissions

I have a summary card for a web-based application which expands into an interactive table that consists of different users and permissions from Custom to Read, Write, Deploy, etc. There will be dropdown fields to add projects and permissions.

[image]

Attached image with one user but will be repeated to create more users.

The requirements are:

1. Projects can have one or more permissions but won't be a lot (done)
2. Permission types will be growing (that's why I used a dropdown)
3. There should be a summary of projects with permissions and expand in a table format for users to add, edit, delete project permissions (located on top of the mockup)
4. It is important to see custom permissions from different projects than to see all possible permission types. If there is more than one project with the same permission type, a tooltip will be used to indicate more.
5. There could be up to three rows for the summary and show more details on expanding the summary card. If there are more than 3 rows in the summary, the rest of the details will be in the expanded table.

My questions are:

- How might we present the summary in a cleaner way where if the user expands the card, the data is still readable in the same order as the summary?
- The way it is arranged is that the permissions are grouped in the summary (1st row left to right, 2nd row left to right, etc.) and from top to bottom on the interactive table.  I'm not quite convinced that the flow is readable or visually appealing. Does adding a pie chart in the summary help?
- Grouping the permissions into separate columns might not be possible because the permission types will be a growing list and the user adds a new row, input the project name, and set permissions in a row.
- The permissions custom, read, write, deploy, etc. are listed vertically while the summary displays them horizontally. Is this acceptable? Perhaps add a label in each row to make it more clear that the permissions are sorted automatically? Or add labels and separate "add row" per permission type?
- Does auto-sorting work in this case? The way I imagine it would function from this layout is when a user sets permission to a project in a new row, that row will automatically be arranged under the same permission type.  Just like how Gmail alphabetically arrange labels after input.

Is there a better way of solving this problem?

Comment: Hi @telo78, thanks for your contribution to UXSE :) This is a very detailed question with lots of information, so my suggestion would be to try and break up some of the information into smaller chunks (and questions) and that way we can focus on each specific issue and provide an appropriate response to it (if it makes sense to do so since some are more related to others).

Comment: Good idea, @MichaelLai will do

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion - dropdown isn't good solution in this case.

**How might we present the summary in a cleaner way where if the user expands the card, the data is still readable in the same order as the summary?**

I'm not sure that at the time of occurrence of e.g. 4-5 accesses - 
 dropdown is still a good solution (many combinations)
You can consider to introduce **checkboxes**

[image]
When the system will grow up, you can enter something like permission    inheritance. (i.e. the user has the same rights in B as in A)

**The way it is arranged is that the permissions are grouped in the summary (1st row left to right, 2nd row left to right, etc.) and from top to bottom on the interactive table. I'm not quite convinced that the flow is readable or visually appealing. Does adding a pie chart in the summary help?**

In accordance with the principle of Z - in our culture we read from left to right

[image]

**Grouping the permissions into separate columns might not be possible because the permission types will be a growing list and the user adds a new row, input the project name, and set permissions in a row.**

If grouping in the column is not possible so that it is worth **categorizing** and **developing** a group of users instead of selected rights.

- **User** - can read write
- **Admin** - can everything
- **Devops** - can read, write, deploy

However, this approach requires a lot of analytical and implementation work.

**The permissions custom, read, write, deploy, etc. are listed vertically while the summary displays them horizontally. Is this acceptable? Perhaps add a label in each row to make it more clear that the permissions are sorted automatically? Or add labels and separate "add row" per permission type?**

Yes, multiselect, when labels displays horizontally is acceptable as in the picture below.
[image]

**Does auto-sorting work in this case? The way I imagine it would function from this layout is when a user sets permission to a project in a new row, that row will automatically be arranged under the same permission type. Just like how Gmail alphabetically arrange labels after input.**

Possible, but difficult to implement - in this case, you could filter by permission. 
It is helpfull to limit the possible rights at this stage(to start testing). The programming solution should be generic in this case

Comment: Thanks for validating.  Still not quite convinced about the summary card.  Would be nice to show a clean text UI, click to expand to see the fields.  I used checkboxes as an alternate answer but we didn't continue w/ it.  I also tried implementing roles but we'll be using permissions for all users.  Multi-select is the approach we are using as included in the image attached but still not convinced on vertically positioning them.  Maybe group the permissions which are table chunks: https://www.uxpincdn.com/studio/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/unnamed-2.png

Comment: If group permissions, which are table chunks - then drag&drop is possible.

Comment: I'll present it to my lead developer :) or create/customize their own permission.

Comment: Filtering by permission is a great idea as well.  Trying to think of other ways but it is coming down to it.